# JavaScript: Can not get hold of values of an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

Here is my code

```
var dataGroupByParentCategory = function(data){
 return _.groupBy(data, function(entry){
    return entry.category.parent;
  });
};


var parentCategorySum = function(data) {  

  var result = {};
  _.forEach(_.keys(this.dataGroupByParentCategory(data)), function(parentCategory){
     var that = this;
     console.log(parentCategory);
     var s = _.reduce(that.dataGroupByParentCategory[parentCategory], function(s, entry){
           console.log('>' + entry);  // Can not see entry here
           return s + parseFloat(entry.amount);
     }, 0);

     result[parentCategory] = s;
  });

  return result;
};
```

and data looks like

```
'data': [
        {
            'category': {
                'uri': '/categories/0b092e7c-4d2c-4eba-8c4e-80937c9e483d',
                'parent': 'Food',
                'name': 'Costco'
            },
            'amount': '15.0',
            'debit': true
        },
        {
            'category': {
                'uri': '/categories/d6c10cd2-e285-4829-ad8d-c1dc1fdeea2e',
                'parent': 'Food',
                'name': 'India Bazaar'
            },
            'amount': '10.0',
            'debit': true
        },
        {
            'category': {
                'uri': '/categories/d6c10cd2-e285-4829-ad8d-c1dc1fdeea2e',
                'parent': 'Food',
                'name': 'Sprouts'
            },
            'amount': '11.1',
            'debit': true
        }, ...
```

**Problem?**

I can not see value of entry as seen in code above

```
       console.log('>' + entry);  // Can not see entry here
```

I am learning JavaScript and not very well versed with concept of scopes, is that is causing issue here?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to `var that = this` outside of the loop. Not sure what `this` is inside Underscore's `.forEach`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `dataGroupByParentCategory` function is global, so you don't need use `this` or `that` to access it. Also it seems you make a typo in `dataGroupByParentCategory[parentCategory]`. It must be `dataGroupByParentCategory(parentCategory)`

Comment: `dataGroupByParentCategory[parentCategory]` makes perfect sense, as @daydreamer is iterating over the keys of `dataGroupByParentCategory` with `_.forEach`. Also, there are plenty of reasons not to just reference something by name like that. -1

Comment: `dataGroupByParentCategory` is a function, not an object that has keys. He iterates over the keys of "result" of `dataGroupByParentCategory` function. Also @daydreamer correct his code by setting a value as `dataGroupByParent` at his answer.

Comment: a) A function *is* an object b) That doesn’t make calling `dataGroupByParentCategory(parentCategory)` any more right as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After spending sometime with code, I realized I was doing it incorrectly, the actual code now is

```
var parentCategorySum = function(data) {

  var result = {};
  var dataGroupByParent = dataGroupByParentCategory(data);
  _.forEach(_.keys(dataGroupByParent), function(parentCategory){
     var s = _.reduce(dataGroupByParent[parentCategory], function(s, entry){
           return s + parseFloat(entry.amount);
     }, 0);
     result[parentCategory] = s;
  });

  return result;
};
```